# Exception error for character array

Tags: java, arrays, indexoutofboundsexception, character-arrays

I am trying to write a program that display's the user's input in reverse. I know that there are better ways to do this but let me make a long story short by saying my teacher is not the most understanding of individuals that being said here's what I got so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) 
{
    String input;
    int len;

    input = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, "Please enter a string value: ");
    len = input.length();
    char[] txt = new char[len];
    for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
    {
        txt[i] = input.charAt(i);
    }
    for (int j = len; j >= 0; j--)
    {
        System.out.print(txt[j]);
    }
}
```

The error I keep receiving is as follows:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 7
    at *program*.main(*program*.java:28)

It points to the line:

```
System.out.print(txt[j]);
```

I understand that the error is saying that I have exceeded the limits of the array I'm just not seeing how.
Any help or input will be greatly appreciated. Thank You.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What causes a java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException and how do I prevent it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5554734/what-causes-a-java-lang-arrayindexoutofboundsexception-and-how-do-i-prevent-it)

Comment: As a side note, given the error you receive, I understand your teacher insisting on you getting this to work. Were I a teacher, I would expect a student to fully understand loops before starting to take shortcuts.

Answer (score 3):

Replace

```
for (int i = 0; i <= len; i++)
```

with

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
```

And

```
for (int j = len; j >= 0; j--) {
```

with

```
for (int j = len-1; j >= 0; j--) {
```

Array indexes are zero-based, and end at array length - 1.

Comment: I knew it was something simple. Just a little burned out, I guess. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 2):

Please change the looping condition in your for 1st loop !

```
i <= len
```

to

```
i < len
```

It goes from 0 ... n-1

Also you need to change initialization condition in 2nd loop

```
int j = len
```

to

```
int j = len-1
```

It goes from n-1 ... 0

Answer (score 1):

Iterate over the array from (length-1) to 0.
Array [length] is resulting in the IndexOutOfBoundsException.

Example code:

```
for (int i = 0; i < len; i++){
    txt[i] = input.charAt(i);
}
for (int j = len-1; j >= 0; j--){
    System.out.print(txt[j]);
}
```